# Customizing HomeKit (using HomeBridge plug-in or building custom app?)

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, adobe, homekit, ios-homekit

I am running HomeBridge on a RBPi3 and displaying my home accessories through an iPad hub running the Home app.

I really like it but I'm missing some things like a big clock (The iPad is hanging on my kitchen wall with screen-on display most of the day), a summary of my Google Calendar and some other nice widgets. It is not possible to add those widgets to the Home app (typically so with Apple software .. :-)) but I'm looking for a solution to achieve this.

I have two options (at least that's what I think):

1) Build my own iPad using the HomeKit API where I can then customize the app appearance and add the widgets the way I want.

2) Using HomeBridge FFMpeg camera plugin and creating a video stream containing a big clock and some calendar item titles.

Option 1 is the most work but also provides the flexibility. Option 2 is easier but limited in functionality. Option 2 might also be a performance overkill to have a video stream? The video stream would provide me with the advantage that the camera widget in HomeKit is pretty big and clearly visible from distance (the clock at least).

What do you think is the best option and how would option 2 be achieved? How can I set up a video stream from for example a SWF file created in Adobe Animate? Or how to achieve this dynamic info inside a video stream?

Any tips are most welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try HomeAssistant with HomeKit controller and possibly with HomeBridge plugin for custom accessories already configured on HomeBridge:

[HomeAssistant Dashboard Screenshot](https://www.home-assistant.io/images/hadashboard/dash1.png)

References:

1) [HomeAssistant Installation](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/installation/)

2) [HomeAssistant Dashboard](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/ecosystem/hadashboard/)

3) [HomeAssistant Controller](https://www.home-assistant.io/components/homekit_controller/)

4) [HomeAssistant HomeBridge Add-on](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/community-hass-io-add-on-homebridge/33803)